# average_rating column for a Rating Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm creating a rating (stars) Model:

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "total_stars",   default: 0, null: false
    t.integer  "average_stars", default: 0, null: false
  end

  create_table "stars", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "starable_id"
    t.string   "starable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "number"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

So I already know how to get the total stars:

**star.rb:**

```
  def add_to_total_stars
    if [Post].include?(starable.class)
      self.starable.update_column(:total_stars, starable.total_stars + self.number)
    end
  end
```

But for the average stars:

```
  def calculate_average_stars
    if [Post].include?(starable.class)
      self.starable.update_column(:average_stars, [SOMETHING MISSING HERE])
    end
  end
```

I'm having some problems.

I guess I have to create a column which will store all the `numbers` the post has so I can do something like this:

```
2 + 4 + 2 / total_stars
```

**EDIT:**

OK, I tried this:

```
  def calculate_average_stars
    if [Post].include?(starable.class)
      stars_list = self.starable.stars.map { |t| stars_list = t.number }   
      self.starable.update_column(:average_stars, stars_list.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / stars_list.size)
    end
  end
```

But I get this error:

```
1.9.3-p0 :010 > star5.save
   (0.6ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "total_stars" = 4 WHERE "posts"."id" = 5
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "average_stars" = NaN WHERE "posts"."id" = 5
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: NaN: UPDATE "posts" SET "average_stars" = NaN WHERE "posts"."id" = 5
   (0.6ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: NaN: UPDATE "posts" SET "average_stars" = NaN WHERE "posts"."id" = 5
```

Any suggestions of how to create such table?

Comment: so a star belongs_to :starable, and a post has_many :stars - what is a starable.class in the methods in post.rb? And is [Post].include? really called on an array containing the class Post as its sole element, or do you mean self.include?

Comment: @bgates Just checking if the the starable is a `Post` it doesn't have much to do with the method actually.

Comment: Oh #add_to_total_stars and calculate_average_stars are in star.rb, right? Not post.rb.

Comment: @bgates oh, my mistake. The code it's actually in star.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, if you already have #total_stars, can't you just do

```
def calculate_average_stars
  if [Post].include?(starable.class)
    self.starable.update_column(:average_stars, total_stars / stars.count)
  end
end
```

-and change the posts table so that average_stars can be a float instead of an integer?